# Left align sidewaystable

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, rotating

Is it possible to left align a `sidewaytable` to make use of the extra space at the left of it? Similar to the `\LTleft\fill` in `longtable`? I have not found a way to do this yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sidewaystable` environment is a floating (and rotated) environment, but it does not in itself provide instructions on how to typeset tabular material. For that, you need to specify a `tabular`, `tabularx`, `tabular*`, etc environment *inside* the `sidewaystable` environment. (In other words, the `sidewaystable` environment behaves exactly like the "ordinary" `table` environment does, except that it rotates its contents and places them on a separate page.)

For instance, to suppress the horizontal whitespace at the left and right-hand ends of a `tabular` environment that has four columns (the first left-justified, the remaining three centered), you should specify something like

```
\begin{tabular}{ @{} lccc @{} }
...
\end{tabular}
```

The `@{}` group tells LaTeX to suppress the horizontal whitespace.

If you're using a `tabular*` environment with a width equal to `\textwidth`, i.e., the full width of the text block, you could also specify

```
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{ @{\extracolsep{\fill}} lccc }
...
\end{tabular*}
```